# Updating react component when redux state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using redux for state management. I am using a component that includes a table and a form to update the entries on that table. I am calling the useSelector at the top of the component. I have a sorting function that the data from useSelector is passed on to, the function sorts it and returns a function, which I then map onto the table. However, everytime I add or edit an entry on the form, the sorting function fails. I noticed it's because the component doesn't re-render when the data in dispatch updates. How can I fix this?
*** The Component ***

```
function Users() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [ openPopup, setOpenPopup ] = useState(false);
  const [ loading ] = useFetchHook(fetchUsers());
  const { users } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const [ filterFunc, setFilterFunc ] = useState({
    func: (items) => {
      return items;
    }
  });
//Table hook where "users" data is passed and returns "recordsAfterSorting"
  const { TableContainer, TableHeader, TablePagination, recordsAfterSorting } = useTable(
    users
  );

return (

        <TableContainer>
          <TableHeader />

          <TableBody>
            {recordsAfterSorting().map((item) => (
              <TableRow key={item.id}>
                <TableCell>{item.id}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  {item.firstname} {item.lastname}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>{item.is_admin ? 'Yes' : 'No'}</TableCell>

                <TableCell>
                  {/* <ActionButton color='primary' onClick={() => openInPopup(item)}>
                        <EditOutlined fontSize='small' />
                      </ActionButton> */}

                  <ActionButton
                    color='secondary'
                    onClick={() =>
                      setConfirmDialog({
                        isOpen: true,
                        title: `Are you sure you want to delete ${item.firstname}'s account?`,
                        subtitle: "You can't undo this operation",
                        onConfirm: () => {
                          handleDelete(item.id);
                        }
                      })}>
                    <Close fontSize='small' />
                  </ActionButton>
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </TableContainer>

<Popup openPopup={openPopup} setOpenPopup={setOpenPopup} title='Add New User'>
        <Registration recordForEdit={recordForEdit} addOrEdit={addOrEdit} />
      </Popup>
     <ConfirmDialog confirmDialog={confirmDialog} setConfirmDialog={setConfirmDialog} />
    )
}
```

*** TableHook ***

```
export default function useTable(records, headCells, filterFunc) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const pages = [ 10, 25, 50 ];
  const [ page, setPage ] = useState(0);
  // const [ rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage ] = useState(pages[page]);
  const [ order, setOrder ] = useState();
  const [ orderBy, setOrderBy ] = useState();

  const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => setPage(newPage);

  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
    setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
    setPage(0);
  };

  const descendingComparator = (a, b, orderBy) => {
    if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) return -1;
    if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) return 1;
    return 0;
  };

  const getComparator = (order, orderBy) => {
    return order === 'desc'
      ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
      : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
  };

  const stableSort = (arr, comparator) => {
    const stabilizedThis = arr.map((el, index) => [ el, index ]);
    stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
      const order = comparator(a[0], b[0]);
      if (order !== 0) return order;
      return a[1] - b[1];
    });
    return stabilizedThis.map((el) => el[0]);
  };

  const recordsAfterSorting = () =>
    stableSort(filterFunc.func(records), getComparator(order, orderBy)).slice(
      page * rowsPerPage,
      (page + 1) * rowsPerPage
    );

  const handleSortRequest = (cellId) => {
    const isAscending = orderBy === cellId && order === 'asc';
    setOrder(isAscending ? 'desc' : 'asc');
    setOrderBy(cellId);
  };

  const TableContainer = ({ children, size=null }) => (
    <Table size={size} className={classes.table}>{children}</Table>
  );
  const TableHeader = () => (
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        {headCells.map((headCell) => (
          <TableCell
            key={headCell.id}
            sortDirection={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : false}>
              {headCell.disableSorting ? headCell.label :
            <TableSortLabel
              active={orderBy === headCell.id}
              direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : 'asc'}
              onClick={() => handleSortRequest(headCell.id)}>
              {headCell.label}
            </TableSortLabel>
              }
          </TableCell>
        ))}
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
  );

  const TablePagination = () => (
    <MuiTablePagination
      component='div'
      page={page}
      rowsPerPageOptions={pages}
      rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
      count={records.length}
      onChangePage={handleChangePage}
      onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
    />
  );

  return { TableContainer, TableHeader, TablePagination, recordsAfterSorting };
}
```

*** Chrome Error ***

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
stableSort
src/hooks/useTable.js:62
  59 | };
  60 | 
  61 | const stableSort = (arr, comparator) => {
> 62 |   const stabilizedThis = arr.map((el, index) => [ el, index ]);
     | ^  63 |   stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
  64 |     const order = comparator(a[0], b[0]);
  65 |     if (order !== 0) return order;
```

Comment: what is your initial value for users ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing `records` to the `useTable()` pass it direrectly to the `recordsAfterSorting()` fn like this:

```
const recordsAfterSorting = (records) =>
    stableSort(filterFunc.func(records), getComparator(order, orderBy)).slice(
      page * rowsPerPage,
      (page + 1) * rowsPerPage
    );
```

And I'm guessing records is equivalent to `users`, so u can use it like this:

```
recordsAfterSorting(users).map((item) => (
```

This should do the trick

Comment: I cannot deconstruct these, they're just variable names for the useTable arguments. If I deconstruct users, I am unable to map over the array. Users is an array.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the values are just passed down into the table hook

Comment: That's the problem I think,  I am not sure if the values are passing down in `useTable` fn are the expected args.

Comment: Arguments you're passing to `useTable` fn: `users`
Arguments expected: `records`, `headCells`, `filterFunc`

Comment: So I tried this, and basically, in the useTable function, it doesn’t matter what the arguments are called. Changing the records to users didn’t make any difference. I looked at the redux devtools in chrome, it looks like once the dispatch inside handleSubmit is called, it doesn’t fetch the users again, thus the data inside users from useSelector has changed but the component doesn’t rerender thus the function that maps through users fails.

Comment: Ok, I think that is basically because `recordsAfterSorting` fn does not have access to the updated `records`

Comment: Thank you SO much Shaswat, you solution worked for 4 of my components. The user component is still having issues, I believe it’s probably how my registration form has been set up. How can I populate the selection options for my form with the data coming from my backend? Currently I’ve hardcoded everything.

Comment: I'm guessing `<Registration recordForEdit={recordForEdit} addOrEdit={addOrEdit} />
` is yout form, and if user is your data, you can pass user to your form like this.
`<Registration recordForEdit={recordForEdit} user={user} addOrEdit={addOrEdit} />`. You'll be able to access it from props.

Comment: I'm so sorry, back to the original question. It turned out, I had commented out e.preventDefault(), so thats why it was working. I realized when I un-commented it, the map function failed again. :-(